Refactor a function
I heve this function into two different component in React in order highlithe a value if it is equal to the one I am searching.
    const generateHighlightedText = useMemo(() => {
      const regex = new RegExp(`(${highlightValue})`, 'gi');
      const markStyles = {
        color: buyingTheme.palette.primary.contrastText,
        backgroundColor: alpha(buyingTheme.palette.primary.main, 0.75),
        borderRadius: 2,
      };
    
      return (text: string, key: string) => {
        if (!highlightValue.trim()) {
          return text;
        }
        return text
          .split(regex)
          .filter(String)
          .map((part, index) =>
            regex.test(part) ? (
              <mark key={`highlightable-mark-${highlightValue}-${key}-${index}`} style={markStyles}>
                {part}
              </mark>
            ) : (
              <span key={`highlightable-span-${highlightValue}-${key}-${index}`}>{part}</span>
            ),
          );
      };
    }, [highlightValue, buyingTheme.palette.primary.contrastText, buyingTheme.palette.primary.main]);

I have to refactor the code and to move the function to another file and then import it into the two componentes.
I created a util folder with a highlithed.util.ts file and I copied and pasted the fn and the importation.
It is now breaking everywhere and some of the errors are:

cannot find name span neither mark
do I have to define any parametres to the fn?
do I have to define any type or interface?

Don't know how to continue

If you want to convert your generateHighlightedText into a reusuable hook.

You need to prefix it's name with use, like this useGeneratedHighlightedText.

It looks like you want to still memoize the returned implementation with function parameters. You'll need to make use of useCallback for that.


Define your custom hook like this:
export const useGenerateHighlightedText = () => {
  const { palette } = useTheme();
  const { buyingTheme} = useBuyingTheme();
  const { searchQuery } = useHeaderWithSearchbar();

  const regex = new RegExp(`(${searchQuery})`, 'gi');
  const markStyles = {
    color: buyingTheme.palette.primary.contrastText,
    backgroundColor: alpha(buyingTheme.palette.primary.main, 0.75),
    borderRadius: 2,
  };

  return useCallback((text: string, key: string) => {
    if (!searchQuery.trim()) {
      return text;
    }
    return text
      .split(regex)
      .filter(String)
      .map((part, index) =>
        regex.test(part) ? (
          <mark key={`highlightable-mark-${searchQuery}-${key}-${index}`} style={markStyles}>
            {part}
          </mark>
        ) : (
          <span key={`highlightable-span-${searchQuery}-${key}-${index}`}>{part}</span>
        )
      );
  }, [searchQuery, buyingTheme.palette.primary.contrastText, buyingTheme.palette.primary.main]);
}

Now you can implement it like this:
const MyComponent = () => {
  const generateHighlightedText = useGenerateHighlightedText();

  generateHighlightedText('myText', 'myKey');

  ...
}


Actually there is no need for memoization inside external functions and I can't use hook into a .ts file. I copied the code knowing that it was not the correct solution.

I'm not sure what you want...

So, just ferget the second piece of code I wrote.
I have one function in two different react compoentnes and I need to move it to a new .ts file.  When I copy and pasted it breaks everywhere I don't know how to solve it.
I know I cannot use hooks into a .ts file; then, it cannot find the name span and mark:
Finally if I eliminate the dependenci array, I don't knw if I should add any  parametres to the fn.

I'm not sure why you keep saying you cannot use hooks in a .ts file.

My custom hook approach is exactly what it sounds like you say you need.

It improves a bit but I still got the error with the  and with the :

if I hover on mark I receive this message
Cannot find name 'mark'.
if I hover on part
Unreachable code detected.ts
Operator '>' cannot be applied to types '{ markStyles: { color: any; backgroundColor: string; borderRadius: number; }; }' and '{ part: any; }'.ts
Operator '<' cannot be applied to types 'boolean' and 'RegExp'.ts
No value exists in scope for the shorthand property 'part'. Either declare one or provide an initializer


Thank Barry you were right. I had to change couple of things from your code but now it is working.

So, does that make this an accepted answer? :P
